# Can Cargo run external tools before compilation?

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

Is it possible to have cargo run external tools before compiling the code?

The exact problem that I am having:

I have a parser generator which is created using [re2rust](https://re2c.org/manual/manual_rust.html). This parser generator takes a file as an input and generates rust code (a source file). I need to run the parser generator before compiling the core. Ideally only if the original file was modified.

I can't find cargo docs on how to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a `build.rs` script. Docs are [here](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/build-scripts.html) but the gist for your use case would be something like

```
fn main() {
    println!("cargo:rerun-if-changed=path/to/template");
    Command::new("re2rust")
        .arg(/*whatever*/)
        .output()
        .expect("failed to execute process")
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to create a [`build.rs`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/build-scripts.html) file.
It can do anything that a rust binary could.

```rust
fn main() -> std::io::Result<()> {
    println!("cargo:rerun-if-changed=re2rust/templates");
    Command::new("re2rust").output()?;
    Ok(())
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For completeness, here is a complete `build.rs` for the case, when the tool writes output to stdout only.

```rust
use std::fs::File;
use std::process::Command;

fn main()  {
    println!("cargo:rerun-if-changed=<full path from cargo root to input file>");

    let rust_file = File::create("<output file>").expect("failed to open parser.rs");

    Command::new("re2rust")
        .current_dir("<input file dir>")
        .arg("<input file>")
        .stdout(rust_file)
        .spawn().expect("failed to execute re2rust");
}
```